# Proof of Wald's Identity, is this valid?

Tags: probability-theory

So Wald says that assuming that $T$ a stopping time and $X_i$ i.i.d. variables are $L^1$, that $E[S_{T}] = E[T]E[X_1]$ given that $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$.  Consider the following proof that is simpler than the one given in my textbook:
$$
\mathbb{E}[S_T] = \sum_{t \in \mathbb{N}} P(T = t)\mathbb{E}[S_t] = \sum_{t \in \mathbb{N}} P(T = t)t\mathbb{E}[X_1] = \mathbb{E}[T]\mathbb{E}[X_1]
$$
there has to be something wrong with it because the book has a more involved one using law of large numbers.

Comment: How do you justify the first equality?